# Calling IBAction declared in other class

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am trying to create an app for the iPhone and I have a main viewController and a number of other viewControllers. This is because it is a multiview application.

In the ViewController.h and ViewController.m files I have created all my IBActions because they will be shared by all the other views.

Now in firstViewController.m I have created a custom button using the following code:

```
UIButton *settingsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
settingsButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
[settingsButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
settingsButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[settingsButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setButtonNormal.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[settingsButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"setButtonPressed.png"];
UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
[settingsButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadSettingsView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:settingsButton];
```

As you can see the action is called "loadSettingsView" which I have correctly declared in ViewController. But it does not work and this is because the above code is in firstViewController.m and NOT in ViewController.m where the IBAction is declared.
Note I have moved the above code in ViewController and the action works, therefore is not a problem of the action. The problem is that I cannot find a way to access the action that has been declared in a different class than the one I am working on.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the way you declare the target of the action for the button

```
[settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadSettingsView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If this piece of code is located in `firstViewController.m` and you say that the target is `self`, it means the compiler must look for the method in the `firstViewController` class. So to fix this problem you need to point the `target` of your button action to point to the `viewController` class. By the way at this point I would like to mention that your naming SUCKS, if you subclass `UIViewController` don't call it `ViewController`, make it more meaningful.

The actual fix.

make a global property that will point to `ViewController` object and call it `vc`.

```
[settingsButton addTarget:vc action:@selector(loadSettingsView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Just a small question. What do you mean by Global Property to point to ViewController?

Comment: You have to have some kind of link to the ViewController class within your firstViewController class. If you called firstViewController as a modal you can reference ViewController thorugh the call to [self parentViewController], but if you didn't you should past a link to firstViewController either through custom init method or through a class variable so that you can later use it to point any button action to it.

Comment: I have tried that way and xcode gives me error again. Can you please tell me how to define that global property? because it seems that the mistake is there

Comment: I have found the solution!! ;)